# How can I bind existing container to another one?

Tags: .net, unity-container

I have instance inherited from `UnityContainer` class and want to create additional instance that will "inherit" all registrations of the previous one?

Am I correctly understand that `AddExtension` method do what I expect?

```
public class MyUnityContainer : UnityContainer
{
 public MyUnityContainer(MyUnityContainer containerParent)
 { 
   if ( containerParent!=null )
     this.AddExtention(containerParent);
 }

 public static void Test()
 {
   MyUnityContainer cont1 = new MyUnityContainer();
   cont1.RegisterType<IA,A>();
   MyUnityContainer cont2 = new MyUnityContainer(cont1);
   IA a = cont2.Resolve<IA>();
}
```

Should this work? If not, what is a way to achieve such functionality?

I could make `MyUnityContainer` not inherited from `UnityContainer`, but containing it ("has a" instead of "is a"), but I don't want to implement `IUnityContainer` interface in my `MyUnityContainer` class.

Answer (score -1):

No, that's not what extensions do. Extensions add new features or registrations to the container, not set up inheritance relationships.

What you want is a child container. You call parent.CreateChildContainer, and that should do what you want - except that the child will be a UnityContainer, not MyUnityContainer.

What does MyUnityContainer do? Perhaps there's a way to make it work without the subclass?